# Passing numerically indexed PHP array to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I've got a PHP array in this format:

```
        $js_data_array[] = array('href' =>$matches[1][0], //this is an image url
                                'title' =>'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit',
                                 );
```

And I need to get it into this format in javascript

```
 [{
'href' : 'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4213562882_851e92f326.jpg',
'title' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
},{
'href' : 'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4213562882_851e92f326.jpg',
'title' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
}]
```

I'm using wp_localise_script() in wordpress to pass the data which doesn't seem to accept a json encoded array.

If I pass the array as is, I get a numerically indexed array with duplicate values of 'Array'

So, the question is, how can I pass the data as an array but without the numeric indexes? I can't have duplicate keys in a php array AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that wp_localize_script() encodes quotes. I therefore did a replace of " in the JS:

```
gallery_data = image.data.replace(/&quot;/g,'"');
```

Answer (score 1):

see [json_encode()](http://docs.php.net/json_encode)

e.g.

```
$matches = array(1=>array(0=>'foo'));
$js_data_array = array();

$js_data_array[] = array(
'href' =>$matches[1][0], //this is an image url
  'title' =>'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit',
);
$js_data_array[] = array(
 'href' =>$matches[1][0], //this is an image url
  'title' =>'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit',
);

echo $json = json_encode($js_data_array);
```

prints

```
[{"href":"foo","title":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"},{"href":"foo","title":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"}]
```

Comment: yeah thanks but I've tried that and can't use it with wp_localise_script()

Comment: When I log the the JSON output to the firebug console I get a string instead of an object e.g:

"[{&quot;href&quot;:&quot;/files/2010/06/Bioreactor-4.jpg&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit&quot;},.....

Is that because of the &quot;?

Comment: From what I read here: http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2010/05/07/adding-scripts-properly-to-wordpress-part-2-javascript-localization/ that's not how you use this wp_localise_script() anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the wp function `wp_specialchars_decode()` when decoding your json data :

```
wp_specialchars_decode($json, ENT_QUOTES)
```

Where `$json` is your encoded array.